# Add a sorting transition while the list is being sorted

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to apply some sort of sorting transition when the user starts inputting a filter and the list is being culled.

Perhaps a slow fade out plus a movement. It is hard for me to describe what I am visualising. Any help would be appreciated, or any code of how the animation will look will also help.

```js
        function myFunction() {
          var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
          input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
          filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
          ul = document.getElementById("myMenu");
          li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
          for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
              li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }

        function removeImg() {
          let input = document.getElementById("mySearch")
          var inputValue = input.value;
          if (inputValue) {
              input.classList.remove("with-image")
              console.log("removed");
          } else {
              input.classList.add("with-image")
              console.log("added");
          }
      }
```

```css
li a {

  text-decoration: none;
  min-width: 70%;
  max-width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 15px;
  transition: rotate .25s ease-in-out;

}

ul {

  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0px;
  columns: 3;

}

input {

  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;

}

.centre {

  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;

}

a {

  display:inline-block;

}

.searchSection {

  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;

}
```

```html
        <div class="searchSection">

            <input type="text" class="with-image" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" onfocus="removeAttr()" onblur="removeImg()" title="Type in a category">

            <ul id="myMenu">
              <li> <a href="errors/dfv0008.html"> DFV0008: MDU <p class="goTo">Go to</p> </a> </li>
              <li> <a href="#"> DFV0004 <p class="goTo">Go to</p> </a> </li>
              <li> <a href="#"> DGS03: Exhaust Fan Unable to Turn On <p class="goTo">Go to</p> </a> </li>
              <li> <a href="#"> DGS04: Chamber Valve Unable to Open <p class="goTo">Go to</p> </a> </li>
              <li> <a href="#"> DGS05: Destruct Valve Unable To Open <p class="goTo">Go to</p> </a> </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a css animation.

Css:

```css
.fadeOut {
  animation: fadeOut 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
    max-width: 0;
    max-height: 0;
  }
}
```

Js

```js
if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    li[i].classList.remove('fadeOut');
} else {
    li[i].classList.add('fadeOut');
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myMenu");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].classList.remove('fadeOut');
    } else {
      li[i].classList.add('fadeOut');
    }
  }
}

function removeImg() {
  let input = document.getElementById("mySearch")
  var inputValue = input.value;
  if (inputValue) {
    input.classList.remove("with-image")
    console.log("removed");
  } else {
    input.classList.add("with-image")
    console.log("added");
  }
}
```

```css
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  min-width: 70%;
  max-width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 15px;
  transition: rotate .25s ease-in-out;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0px;
  columns: 3;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.centre {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.searchSection {
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
}

.fadeOut {
  animation: fadeOut 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
    max-width: 0;
    max-height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="searchSection">
  <input type="text" class="with-image" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" onfocus="removeAttr()" onblur="removeImg()" title="Type in a category">
  <ul id="myMenu">
    <li> <a href="errors/dfv0008.html"> DFV0008: MDU <p class="goTo">Go to</p> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> DFV0004 <p class="goTo">Go to</p> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> DGS03: Exhaust Fan Unable to Turn On <p class="goTo">Go to</p> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> DGS04: Chamber Valve Unable to Open <p class="goTo">Go to</p> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> DGS05: Destruct Valve Unable To Open <p class="goTo">Go to</p> </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```